# Returning json from c# method to Twilio Autopilot

Tags: c#, .net, twilio

I have a task created in Autopilot and one of the actions is to redirect to a url.  This .net code then looks up the caller and replies back info based on whether the caller on file or not.  The task redirect passes control properly to the specified method where I create a json action to continue processing.  The Twilio Docs state to return json, which I do and nothing happens except I get an 'bad request' error in Twilio debugger.  What is the correct syntax for returning json to autopilot.

```
String msg = "I found you contact info";
StringBuilder act = new StringBuilder();
act.AppendLine("{\"actions\": [");
act.AppendLine("{\"say\": \"" + msg+"\"}");
act.AppendLine("]}");
Console.WriteLine(act.ToString());
```

Comment: What are you using to receive the incoming webhook request from Twilio?

Comment: I'm note sure what you're asking.  From within autopilot I do a 'redirect' from a task to my app.  My app then calls a method based on the 'CurrentTask'.  Once I do the appropriate db searches I create a 'action' and attempt to return it to the autopilot to continue processing.  I've tried a simple 'return json' and 'Console.WriteLine(json)' both of which give me a bad request error in the twilio console.  I tested the json by pasting it directly into a task in autopilot and it works fine, so the json is formatted correctly.  Something is not working when I attempt to return the json.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant what web framework are you using?

Comment: The way you have it is correct. Basically, twilio [redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/redirect) accepts an action or a task name in JSON. With just the code provided there should not be a bad request. I would check the response payload and headers.

Comment: I appreciate the input.  I've been communicating with Twilio support and they can't even give me an answer or a snippet of code that works.  Over a week now and no good viable response from Twilio.  There other products are great and I've have good success with them.  Without being able to redirect the flow to my processing and then send it back to autopilot. this may not be the product for me.

Comment: What is the flow you are trying to achieve. Try using [collect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect) has a `on_complete` webhook where you can return`"redirect": "task://task_name"` as an action and have `task_name` say `I found you contact info`. Also look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56382328/4201229)

Comment: I looked at the link you provided and used that same syntax, but still got the 'bad request'.  The flow I'm looking for is I collect info from a caller about a time off request.  My app then looks up the phone number to verify the caller and then updates db and notifies the supervisor via sms. I actually want to return a string like "Your time off request for Mon, Jun 3 for a dr. appt. has been submitted and your supervisor has been notified"  So I have to be able to pass back the data to get autopilot to continue asking ?? and responding.

Comment: That is the absolutely use case of `collect`. Let get started by making a simple flow working with your webhook, I am assuming you are getting the error in twilio's debugger ? What is the exact error ? What is the message you get ? What is the exact response your webhook is sending? What kind of twilio account are you using (trial\paid) ? The number you are using is it marked as trusted on your twilio account ? Please update your question so we can diagnose it properly.

Comment: 1. The error is in Twilio's debugger. 2. exact error code: 11200 3. msg: "Bad Request". 4. sent response: "{"actions": [{"say": "Your time off request has been submitted."}]}" 5. paid Twilio acct. 6. I'm not sure what you mean by 'trusted on my twilio acct'.  Since you last comment I did change my return value to "{"actions":[{"redirect":{"uri":"task://empl_timeoff_submitted"}}]}" and got the same bad request.  the task simply has a say action "Your time off request has been submitted".

Comment: Actually the way you route to another task is not with `uri` it's with just redirect so it should be `{"actions":[{"redirect": "task://empl_timeoff_submitted"}]}`
I have generated two URL you can post to make sure your task is set up the right way
1- `http://demo9894263.mockable.io/say` - Just says "Your time off request has been submitted."
2- `http://demo9894263.mockable.io/redirect_to_empl_timeoff_submitted` - redirects to your task name `empl_timeoff_submitted`

put those in you initial task on autopilot.

Comment: Forgot to mention it but both those url are expecting a POST so your tasks would be `{"actions":[{"redirect": {"uri": "put_those_url_here","method": "POST"}}]}` 
Don't worry about trusted phone numbers its only if you have a trial account. Since you have paid account it's good.

Comment: I inserted each mockable url in the initial task and it worked as expected.  I  then used the 'redirect' action to return json from my app and got a 'bad request' again.

Comment: Yup I saw you incoming request. So we know its not your task, it your webhook response. Use fiddler (or whatever to capture the outgoing response). You'll find something interesting there to work off.

Comment: from fiddler this is my syntaxview "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response></Response>".  Should the json be within the <Response> tag?

Comment: I am not sure. Fiddler should just show you everything you need. The code provided on the question is that the actual code you are running against. If not I would put the exact method on the question so that all the details are there.

Comment: I'm still stumped and not getting any help from Twilio. I really appreciate your (Yash M) helpful suggestions.  Without being able to return json autopilot just may not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here...

Super sorry it's taking so long to answer this question. Hope this answer helps you out. We took a look at your question and built a possible solution on my 7/30 Twitch stream (https://www.twitch.tv/cldubya).

There are 3 approaches you can take.

```
/* EXAMPLE 1: String Result */
var data = @"{""actions"":[{""say"":""This is your new Task""}]}";

/* EXAMPLE 2: Anonymous Types */
var data = new
{
    actions = new[] 
    {
        new { say = "This is Your New Task" }
    }
};
```

The 3rd solution is strongly typed and requires a bit more code. So I haven't posted it here but I would recommend taking a look at the stream for that solution for now. When I post it to Github I will update this answer with the repo link.

Hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: Here a link to the stream referenced in the answer: https://www.twitch.tv/videos/461775732